# How to check if an attribute exists in a json using jq?

Tags: jq

Hi I am having a shell script ,
the shell script  has a variable named RESPONSE

I want a to check if the json object has an attribute named "address" is present. Also how to get value of the attribute address . I want to use jq library

```
#!/bin/bash

RESPONSE={"content-length":"2","address":"192.168.123.1","path":"/hello-world"}
```

appreciate any help

Comment: `jq .address` ??

Comment: What do you want to do if it exists? `jq .address` will give you the value of the address field

Comment: i want to check if it exists . if it exists i want to retrieve the value. if the value is not present the i want to exit the script

Comment: So simply retrieve the value with `.address`. That's the second example in the jq manual. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: thank you it works i tried the following   jq '.address' <<< "$RESPONSE"

Comment: @prasanth If you consider `{"address": null}` or `{"address": false}` as a (practically) non-existent case, you're fine. Otherwise, checking if the field has a truthy value, is not enough. You'd then need to explicitly check its existence, e.g. using `has`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `jq '.address'` will output the value of the property `value`, e.g. `"192.168.123.1"`. (`jq -r` to get rid of the quote marks)
2. `jq 'has(.address)'` will output `true`/`false`
3. `jq -e 'has(.address)' >/dev/null` will set the process' exit status to `0`/`1` depending on the object having the key "address" (regardless of value)
4. `jq -e '.address' >/dev/null` will set the process' exit status to `0` if the "address" property has a *truthy* value (anything except `null` or `false`). A `null` or `false` valued property will set the exit code to `1`.

Having the appropriate exit status allows you to do things such as:

```bash
if jq -e '.address' >/dev/null; then
  echo 'object has address field'
fi
# or:
jq -e 'has("address")' >/dev/null || echo 'object does not have an address'
```

Comment: Isn't the prefix `.` as in `has(.address)` unwarranted?

Comment: @rookie099 whoops, thanks for noticing. I have fixed my post